# Kommasetzung und Strukturanalyse bei Verneinung im Nebensatz

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, punctuation

Das Thema lässt mich nicht los.
Die Regeln sind eindeutig in diesem Satz:

> Ich warte nicht, bis du kommst.

Es gibt zwar eine Mehrdeutigkeit, aber wie ich gelernt habe, ist hier ein Komma, da hier ein finites Verb ist. Was ist aber, wenn man das *nicht* in den Nebensatz zieht.

> Ich warte, nicht bis du kommst, aber doch zumindest ein Weilchen.

Man würde beim Sprechen nach **warte** eine deutliche Cäsur machen.
Hier nun meine Fragen:

- ist das Komma richtig oder muss da ein Semikolon oder Bindestrich hin?
- muss vielleicht nach **nicht** auch ein Komma so wie in dieser Konstellation?

> Ich warte ein Weilchen, aber nicht, bis du kommst.

Und wenn nicht, dann:

- grammatisch steht im Nebensatz die Subjunktion in der linken Satzklammer. Heißt das, dass das **nicht** im Vorfeld steht oder ist das **nicht** eine Position 0, so wie **aber**?

Comment: So oder so muss vor *aber*, wenn als Konjunktion verwendet, immer ein Komma stehen, auch in deinen Beispielsätzen.

Comment: Watt?? Auch wenn dann gar kein Verb kommt so wie in den Beispielen?

Comment: http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/Aufzaehlung.html?lang=en#Anchor-Vor-49575 - "Er ist streng, aber gerecht."

Comment: Mein Gott, das letzte Beispiel sieht ja dann mal richtig sch**ße aus ... pfui Kommaregeln, Pfui

Comment: "Ich warte ein Weilchen, aber nicht bis du kommst, sondern nur für 10 Minuten"

Comment: Also nicht nach "aber nicht"?? Weil das eine Formel ist oder kein Verb hat? Und wenn der Satz so wäre, dann aber schon Komma? "Ich warte ein Weilchen, aber ich warte nicht, bis du kommst."... das macht doch alles keinen Sinn!! Ich glaube, ich schreib' mal einfach weiter so wie ich will ;)

Comment: Hahha. Ja, das Deutsche und die Kommas. Ich hab gestern dazu noch mal den Zwiebelfisch gelesen und da wird gesagt: Eigentlich ist es ganz einfach. Ich sag mal so, es ist unmöglich es immer richtig zu machen. Manchmal darf man, manchmal muss man, manchmal darf man auf keinen Fall. Ich setze auch viele Kommas falsch, aber manchmal muss man einfach drüber hinwegsehen. Ich finde es als wichtig, dass man bei Zweideutigkeiten die Kommas nach Betonung setzt, also "ich warte nicht, bis..." vs "ich warte, nicht bis..." Wenn du dann noch eine Pause nach *nicht* einbaust, erzwingt das aber kein Komma.

Comment: Eigentlich ist das ein wichtiger Punkt. Eine Sprechpause bedeutet meistens auch ein Komma, aber nicht zwingender Weise.Das [Zwiebelfischbeispiel](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-das-gefuehlte-komma-a-305063.html) ist da sehr gut. Das Komma ist falsch, auch wenn du eine Sprechpause machst: "Einen Tag nach dem Absturz einer ägyptischen Chartermaschine über dem Roten Meer, tauchen erste Hinweise auf schwere Sicherheitsmängel bei der Airline auf."

Comment: Bzgl. der ersten Frage: Gedankenstriche und Semikola (und Klammern) sind fast immer durch Kommata (oder »stärkere« Satzzeichen) ersetzbar, ohne dass die orthografische Korrektheit litte. Stilistisch würde ich an dieser Stelle aber klar einen Gedankenstrich bevorzugen.

Comment: Zur zweiten Frage: In beiden Beispielen haben wir es mit einer mehrteiligen Einleitung des Nebensatzes zu tun und dementsprechend braucht nach § 74, E1 kein Komma zu stehen, kann aber ggf. gesetzt werden. Es wäre also auch korrekt: »Ich warte ein Weilchen, aber nicht bis du kommst.«

Answer (score 2):

Ich versuche mal, analytisch aufzudröseln.

Sinneinheiten sind hier:

1. Ich warte [nicht]
2. du kommst
3. [zumindest] ein Weilchen

Ich verwende jetzt folgende Pseudo-Syntax:

1. In eckigen Klammern stehende Wörter sind optional.
2. der Bereich der Konjunktionsverknüpfung ist fettgedruckt dargestellt

Die zwei fraglichen Sätze sind dann also, wenn durch Konjunktionen bzw. Kombinationen von Konjunktionen und dem Negator `nicht` zusammengefügt, wie folgt an den Nahtstellen durch Kommas zu trennen:

> Ich warte [nicht], **[nicht] bis** du kommst, **aber [[je]doch]** [zumindest] ein Weilchen.
>
> Ich warte ein Weilchen, **[aber] [nicht] bis** du kommst.

Man sieht, vor dem Fettgedruckten steht jeweils ein Komma. Dass die logisch zusammengehörende Kombination `aber nicht bis` nicht durch ein Komma zerstückelt werden kann, wird nun klar.

Comment: Ich steig da jetzt irgendwie nicht durch - was ist der Unterschied zwischen dem ersten (nicht-fetten) und dem zweiten (fetten) "nicht" im ersten Satz? Die Sache mit den "#" ist mir auch neu - wofür sind die hier gut? Sorry, aber ich schwimme gerade komplett... :)

Comment: @Mac: Das erste "nicht" negiert das Satzglied, das zweite die Konjunktion "bis". Es zeigt nur die Kombinationsmöglichkeiten auf, die man noch hätte.

Comment: Okay, aber wieso hat man im zweiten Satz diese Wahlmöglichkeit nicht? Kann man da *nur* die Konjunktion negieren? Aber mein Problem ist, dass ich die Herleitung nicht checke. Wenn ich richtig verstehe, setzt Du zunächst fest: die Konjunktionen und optionale Elemente, die davor stehen, sind fettgedruckt. Dann setzt Du vor diese Ausdrücke jeweils ein Komma. Und die Schlussfolgerung ist dann, dass vor diesen Ausdrücken ein Komma steht. Sorry, ich werd wahnsinnig, wenn ich was nicht verstehe... :)

Comment: Ah, ich hatte gerade noch einen anderen Gedanken: Bezieht sich Deine Antwort vielleicht *nur* auf die Frage, ob zwischen "aber nicht" und "bis" ein Komma stehen muss/soll/darf?

Comment: @Mac: nochmal in Kurzform erklärt, wie man bei der Kommasetzung vorgeht: 1.) Du suchst die Konjunktionen bzw. Gruppen von Konjunktionen. Die habe ich für dich schon mal gefunden und als fettgedruckt markiert. 2.) Du setzt vor diese jeweils ein Komma. Innerhalb der Konjunktionsgruppe trennst du nicht mit Komma.

Comment: Okay, dann sind aber die Voraussetzungen und die Schlussfolgerungen dieser Argumentationskette identisch, oder?